# Recaptcha Rails use v2 or version 2 of reCAPTCHA

Tags: ruby-on-rails, captcha, recaptcha

I'm trying to use the latest version of recaptcha, on views, my captcha looks like: [image: current captcha]

I would like it look like https://developers.google.com/recaptcha, here's a picture:

[image]

in my form I have:

```
= form_for [refinery, :inquiries, @inquiry], html: { id: "contact-form" } do |f|    
  = recaptcha_tags display: { display: 'red'}
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this with `gem "recaptcha"`,https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of `recaptcha` that supports the v2 API hasn't been released yet so you need to use the version directly from Github.

```
gem "recaptcha", github: "ambethia/recaptcha"
```

And then in the initializer (`config/initializers/recaptcha.rb`)

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.api_version = "v2"
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the GitHub instruction!

Answer (score 1):

This answer probably just need an update.

I currently solved the problem adding this to the `Gemfile`:

`gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"`

`config.api_version = "v2"` seems not to be supported anymore. That's probably because the support for `V1` was removed from version 1.0.0 ([changelog](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha/blob/2dc66ed502593bc4b837abcce4ac3f43eb1468c6/CHANGELOG.md#100---2015-11-30))